# Constant size of graphics within an image (not image size)

Tags: graphics3d

I can not imagine, that this has not been asked before, but I can't find anything on this...
It is a fast one anyway I guess. I am just looking for the command, which makes the difference in the displaying between the following 2 cases (besides the panel in the second case):

```
Graphics3D[Cube[]]
```

and

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[Cube[]]]
```

Notice, that if you change the ViewPoint of the first one, the graphic within the image is scaled, such that it fits exactly in the image. In the second case, the graphic has "enough space" within the image, such that it fits in the image from every possible ViewPoint, so it does not get scaled, when changing the ViewPoint.

Does someone know how to achieve this properly without Manipulate?

Greetings!

Comment: I tried using `Method->{"ShrinkWrap"->True}` in the `Graphics3D` but this will only erratically re-fit the view after adjusting it and right clicking a couple of times.

Comment: Use `Graphics3D[Cube[], SphericalRegion -> True]`

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot !!